# Bash: how to write in file from a bash script both ${VAR} and values?

Tags: bash

I need to write both variables like ${myvar} and their values.

This code makes no substitutes and writes text as is:

```
cat >${PROGNAME_APPDIR}/AppRun <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash

HERE=$(dirname $(readlink -f "${0}"))
export LD_PRELOAD="${HERE}"/lib/exec_wrapper.so
export BIN_DIR="${HERE}${DIR}"
exec "${BIN_DIR}"/binary "$@"
EOF
```

When I change `<< 'EOF'` to `<< EOF` the code substitutes all. But I need substitute just value of `${DIR}`.

How to make a mixed write without crazy coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` sign, change `$` to `\$` so it is treated as a normal character:

```
cat >${PROGNAME_APPDIR}/AppRun <<EOF
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

HERE=\$(dirname \$(readlink -f "\${0}"))                                                                                                                                                                                                              
export LD_PRELOAD="\${HERE}"/lib/exec_wrapper.so                                                                                                                                                                                                    
export BIN_DIR="\${HERE}${DIR}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
exec "\${BIN_DIR}"/binary "\$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
EOF
```